# no window animations accross app - android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-windowmanager

I am creating an app that i want to NEVER use Window Animations..  I have tried using

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
```

in methods that call new intents..

and i have also tried putting it in my intent filters of my manifest like so:

```
 <data android:name="android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION" />
```

either way only seems to deal with one side of window animation, meaning it seems to still animate in, the intent, just not out..

There has to be a simple way to disable all window animations in an app..

Comment: You don't have the anim when the activity starts, but you do have it when you leave it? Is that the problem?

Comment: i don't want any animation.. and when i switch activities with the above intent i still see animation

Answer (score 0):

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION` cancels the next activity starting animation, but not the current activity ending animation: Try this:

```
startActivity(...); // with your intent containing the flag
finish(); // not sure if this is necessary
overridePendingTransition(0, 0); // this cancels the ending animation
```